# Composer out of memory limit

Tags: php, symfony, dependencies, composer-php

i tried to run `composer update` but i have this error :

`Fatal error: Out of memory <allocated 1520435200> <tried to allocate 268435456 bytes...>`

I try several solution but nothing is working :

- My php.ini is already modify with `memory_limit = -1`
- the command `php -d memory_limit=-1 ../composer.phar update`
- The command `php ../composer.phar install`  (work fine but after i have the same error when i run composer update)
- Try composer self-update to get last version
- Try to edit composer.bat to up the memory

I'm on php 5.5.12, i can't upgrade to php 7.X due to my restrictions.
And i tried to upgrade to php 5.6 and it not solve the problem, always this error : "Out of memory"

Here is my composer.json :

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
        "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": { "Tests\\": "tests/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.12",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.7.1",
        "leafo/scssphp": "~0.6",
        "patchwork/jsqueeze": "~1.0",
        "coresphere/console-bundle": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master",
        "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "^4.0",
        "jms/serializer": "^1.7",
        "vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.4",
        "liuggio/excelbundle": "^2.1",
        "spipu/html2pdf": "^5.0",
        "ob/highcharts-bundle": "^1.6",
        "ocramius/proxy-manager": "^1.0"


    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "symfony-scripts": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "5.5.12"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "3.2-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

maybe something cause a bug and it's not the memory that is the problem but i don't know why.

All solution i found didn't work for me, someone can help please ?

**------ EDIT ------**

So the solution to my problem was to upgrade my OS version to x64 and php5.5 x32 to php 7.2 x64. With these upgrade i can use composer as i want without problem !

Comment: I get the same error on my machine. Have you tried to create an [issue on github](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues)?

Comment: No, but after few hours, i think this is my computer the problem, it have only 4Gb RAM and about 1,8/2Gb available for composer update. This is the only way, i tested all solution and nothing work

Comment: That's strange, I got the same error message despite 16GB RAM.

Comment: Note that this is an "Out of memory" error, not a memory limit error, so configuration is not going to help. It is most likely because you are running 32 bit PHP. I have encountered this before on a XAMPP installation.

Comment: @Padam87 have you resolved the problem with your xampp installation ?

Comment: @odan i create an issue on github, if someone can help me, i will tell you the solution

Comment: No, only installing 64 bit php helped.

Comment: @Padam87 You install that on Linux 32 bit or you had already a 64 bit OS version ? There is no problem to install a 64 bit version on Winodws 32 bit ?